# How do I display the advertisement in my ionic App from my WordPress site?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an app from wordpress websit using rest api but I am not able to find the method to integrate ads into my ionic app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show Admob ads in your Ionic app, then you can use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/

Or you can create a div fixed div at bottom of the page and put the ad code over there. Make sure you put a responsive ad code.

Comment: Html file:     
<ion-content>
  <div class="item-profile" text-center #profilePic [style.background-image]="'url(' + item?.jetpack_featured_media_url + ')'">
  </div>
   <div class="item-detail" padding style=" z-index: 1119">
      <h1  [innerHTML]="item?.title.rendered"></h1>
      <h6>{{item?.date}}</h6>
  </div>  
 
  <div class="item-detail" padding>
    <span [innerHTML]="item?.content.rendered"></span>
  </div>
</ion-content>

Comment: Ts file: 
Ts file:
export class ItemDetailPage {
  item: any;
  getData:any;
  bannerConfig: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  public api:Api, navParams: NavParams, items: Items,public http: HttpClient) {
    var temp = navParams.get('itemName') || items.defaultItem;
    console.log(temp)
    this.getPOst(temp.id)
  }

  getPOst(id){
    this.api.get1('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + id).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data)
      this.item = data
  })
  }